# Regex Expression for special characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g
```

I want include `"` in the following piece of code:

```
onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9"]/g,'')
```

I used the above regex.

The problem I am facing over here is that the above regular expression allows me to include other special characters (`&`, `*`, etc.) into it. How do I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the characters into the character class while taking the correct encoding into account:

```
onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9&quot;&amp;*]/g,'')"
```

Here you need to encode `"` and `&` with the character references `&quot;` and `&amp;` as you’re describing the value of an HTML attribute value declaration.

Answer (score 1):

One first obvious issue with the code is that the `"` that is part of the regex isn't escaped despite it being inside a `"`-delimited string literal. You may want to try and change it to:

`onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\" ]/g,'')`

Comment: Yep, I realized a bit afterwards I wasn't actually answering your question, but just fixing an obvious issue that could have been a blocker to resolution. @Gumbo's answer is a proper one, especially in that context.

Comment: Well I have it working in several context (MS RegEx, Perl, ...=, but I'd effectively think it probably won't work in the context of JavaScript's work on HTML stuff.